# What is max Vce for a transistor with Ic of 50 mA and without exceeding PD(max) of 1.2 W

Tags: npn

What is max Vce for a transistor with Ic of 50 mA and without exceeding PD(max) of 1.2 W?

Comment: hint: power equals voltage times current, in your case you can neglect base current (I suppose), so the dissipated power equals...?

Comment: p=v*i then v= p/c

Comment: So, Vce would be 24v?

Comment: \$\text{V}_{\text{CE,max}}\$, yes. But in practice you wouldn't want to design a circuit at maximum ratings, you would want to be a bit more on the safe side.

Comment: Yeah, i know just want to see if it is too small for the circuit

Comment: @AnthonyHood add your solution as an answer, I'd upvote it so you can have some rep around here

Comment: With high current and voltage across the transistor it's also good to check the SOA (Safe Operating Area) curves to make sure it's okay.

Comment: Beware of transistor ratings. Sometimes they involve unrealistic conditions. For example, case at 25C. But when the junction is at 125C, it will be essentially impossible to keep the case at 25C without refrigeration or something.

Answer (score 1):

> What is max Vce for a transistor

Max Vce has nothing to do with the current you may be drawing thru the collector - it's a limit imposed by the manufacturer of the part irrespective of current flow.

Any transistor conducting 50mA thru the collector may indeed be dissipating 1.2 watts but that tells you nothing about the voltage waveform.

Comment: I think he is trying to figure out the maximum allowable Vce to stay under 1.25W dissipation. I could be misinterpreting, but if that is what he means, then it is a reasonable question.

Comment: @mkeith yes, you may be right but that seems a little simple, as in what is the dc voltage to produce 1.2 watts at 50mA. I'm suspecting he might be considering the 50mA to be the quiescent current and there is a voltage waveform such as sine.